# Nginx: Can I cache a URL matching a pattern at a different URL?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have a site with some URLs that look like this: `/prefix/ID`, where `/prefix` is static and `ID` is unique. Using Nginx as a reverse proxy, I'd like to cache these pages at the `/ID` portion only, omitting the prefix.

Can I configure Nginx so that a request for the original URL is cached at the shortened URL?

I tried this (I'm omitting some irrelevant parts) but obviously it's not the correct solution:

```
http {
    map $request_uri $page_id {
        default $request_uri;
        ~^/prefix/(?<id>.+)$ $id;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_cache_key $page_id
    }
}
```

Comment: _"obviously it's not the correct solution"_ But why?

Comment: ...or I wouldn't need to ask :) Not sure what's happening under the hood, but when I set the cache key like this it serves cached content at `/prefix/ID` but a request for `/ID` is still passed to the app and returns a 404.

Comment: Because `/ID` ($request_uri) isn't the same key as `ID` (~^/prefix/(?<id>.+)$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
map $request_uri $page_id {
    default $request_uri;
    ~^/prefix(?<id>/.+)$ $id;
}
```

Note that leading `/`.

Comment: it may be a bit helpful to provide a bit more instruction here.  The site automatically flagged this is low quality because you didn't put much content into the post.  Maybe an additional set of instructions would be helpful.